# What is the sum of binomial-coefficients multiplied by i?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}i$$

I know this is equivalent to $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{n!i}{i!(n-i)!}$, but the factorial prevents me from solving this easily.

Comment: If you know what a "binomial random variable $X$" is, you could define a system with $n$ independent experiments, each with success probability $p=1/2$, and then $$E[X] = np = \sum_{i=0}^n i{n \choose i}  (1/2)^i(1/2)^{n-i} = (1/2)^n  \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} i $$

Comment: Or you could just note that on $[0,n]$,$\binom n i$ is symmetric around $\frac n 2$ while $i-\frac n 2$ is anti-symmetric, hence the answer is $\frac n 2 2^n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT: Prove and use the identity

$$i\binom{n}i=n\binom{n-1}{i-1}\;;$$

the factor of $n$ can be pulled outside the summation.

Comment: You're so fast :-)

Answer (score 6):

Another way: by Binomial theorem we have$$\left(1+x\right)^{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{i}x^{i}
 $$ then take the derivative $$n\left(1+x\right)^{n-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{i}ix^{i-1}
 $$ and now take $x=1
 $ $$n2^{n-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{i}i.
 $$